# Free alternative to proxycap

Tags: software-rec, proxy

Is there a free/open source alternative to Proxycap apart from FreeCap? (For a HTTP proxy)

What I want is a program that does the proxy authentication for the other programs, so that they can connect without worrying about or needing the user name and password for the proxy server.

Or, is there some local proxy server, like privoxy, which supports authentication through another proxy?

Comment: Have you tried my recommendation for WideCap? I would like to know if it didn't work for you and why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [WideCap](http://www.widecap.com/), freeware since 06 May 2009:

> WideCap - is system proxifier. It was
>   created as extended version of
>   FreeCap program. But WideCap IS NOT a
>   branch or new FreeCap version.
>
> WideCap is fully functional Winsock
>   Service and Namespace provider. That
>   means simply integration into your
>   network subsystem. Forget about this
>   ugly FreeCap's injection, needle to
>   run all programs throught FreeCap,
>   possible errors and incompatible with
>   some firewalls and anti-viruses.
>   WideCap acts as virtual network driver
>   covering all your TCP/IP activity. No
>   launchers - just run your program as
>   usual and work via proxy.

[image]

Comment: After installation on my vista box, I'm unable to add new applications (the button is greyed out) and whenever I click new rule or new proxy I get an exception.

Comment: I've installed it also on Vista: New proxy works well. New applications is grayed out, but that didn't stop me from sliding shortcuts to executables into the View Programs area.

Comment: Strangely, that didn't work for me. And more strangely, if I install it, my Vista stops working. No application is able to run. I uninstall widecap, and everything is back to normal.

Comment: So I've given up, and have written my own program to do it.

Comment: Oh Good. Another freeware for us?

Comment: Yeah will upload the source and binaries as soon as I finish it.

Comment: This software is only available in 32bits it seems, and furthermore, does not even warn about not supporting 64bit programs. (It installs on 64bit windows and works, but only 32bit programs are proxified. The 64bit ones CONNECT DIRECTLY SILENTLY! (Even if "proxify whole system" is set!))

Comment: @Cray: Much has changed since 2009.

Comment: It might be my config, but IE 11 on Win7 x64 didnt connect at all for me, even when widecap wasn't running. As soon as I uninstalled Widecap and restarted IE started working again.

Answer (score 1):

***New Answer :***

[Bypass Proxy Client](http://download.cnet.com/Bypass-Proxy-Client/3000-2144_4-10291385.html)

> The complete network privacy toolBypass Proxy Client is the complete network privacy tool. It ensures absolute privacy wherever you maybe, preventing would-be snoopers from monitoring your surfing, email, or chatting activity. Put an end to blocking filters, firewalls, and proxies. Surf, chat, read news boards, and get all your email at work, on campus (or in regions/areas that may block controversial websites). This client supports HTTP, FTP,SMTP, POP3, NEWS, and SOCKS4 networking, in addition to a direct TUNNEL-ing feature. Bypass supports most OSes and works with standard HTTP and SOCKS proxies.

**OLD Answer :**

[SocksCap](http://soft.softoogle.com/ap/sockscap-download-5157.shtml)

> Automatically enables Windows-based TCP and UDP networking client applications to traverse a SOCKS firewall. SocksCap intercepts the networking calls from WinSock applications and redirects them through the SOCKS server without modifying the original application, the operating system software or drivers.
>   SocksCap is licensed for non-commercial use

Comment: I'm using it for a http proxy rather than a socks proxy.

Comment: I have changed my answer

Comment: This bypasses through their own servers. All I want is a client which will do the authentication for me, so that my programs don't have to worry about proxy authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at http://www.fiddler2.com ? I belive its "chain to upstream gatewat proxy" and "capture WinINet trafffic" functions would do this. Applications that aren't internally using Internet Explorer's HTTP services (WinINet) would have to be configured to use localhost as the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something where you can just change proxy settings within a program and know that everything will be encrypted, you can try [TOR](http://www.torproject.org/easy-download.html.en), their browser bundle does all the hard work for you. Simply use the proxy it sets up and everything works well.