# Openvpn through socks proxy on linux

Tags: linux, routing, openvpn, socks

I hope this is the correct place to post this.

Basically i'm trying to run vpn through a socks proxy. Now this works fine in Windows 7 for me but when i try it in Linux it fails with

```
Code:
Mon Jun 17 23:26:26 2013 [<redacted>] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Mon Jun 17 23:26:26 2013 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Mon Jun 17 23:26:26 2013 Restart pause, 10 second(s)
```

I've tested with Ubuntu 12.x, 13.x and also Debian 7.0. I've tested with the default openvpn 2.2 from the repositories and by compiling 2.3. But i end up with the same error.

Here is my config file.

```
client
dev tun0
proto tcp
socks-proxy 127.0.0.1 9050
remote <redacted> 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind

auth-user-pass p.auth
auth-retry nointeract

ca [inline]

tls-client
tls-auth [inline]
ns-cert-type server

keepalive 10 30
cipher AES-256-CBC
# tls-ciphers currently disabled due to OpenVPN bug.     
# Will hopefully be re-enabled with version 2.3.2.
#tls-cipher TLSv1:!ADH:!SSLv2:!NULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!LOW:!MEDIUM:@STRENGTH
persist-key
persist-tun
comp-lzo
tun-mtu 1500
mssfix
verb 3
```

The full error message

```
Mon Jun 17 23:25:25 2013 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=eth0 HWADDR=00:0c:29:8c:91:9a
Mon Jun 17 23:25:25 2013 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Mon Jun 17 23:25:25 2013 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Mon Jun 17 23:25:25 2013 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Mon Jun 17 23:25:25 2013 /sbin/ifconfig tun0 46.246.35.126 netmask 255.255.255.0 mtu 1500 broadcast 46.246.35.255
Mon Jun 17 23:25:26 2013 /sbin/route add -net 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 192.168.1.1
Mon Jun 17 23:25:26 2013 /sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0 gw 46.246.35.1
Mon Jun 17 23:25:26 2013 /sbin/route add -net 128.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0 gw 46.246.35.1
Mon Jun 17 23:25:26 2013 /sbin/route add -net 46.246.35.2 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 192.168.1.1
Mon Jun 17 23:25:26 2013 Initialization Sequence Completed
Mon Jun 17 23:26:26 2013 [pw.openvpn.ipredator.se] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Mon Jun 17 23:26:26 2013 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Mon Jun 17 23:26:26 2013 Restart pause, 10 second(s)
Mon Jun 17 23:26:36 2013 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->131072] S=[16384->131072]
Mon Jun 17 23:26:36 2013 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:9050 [nonblock]
Mon Jun 17 23:26:36 2013 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:9050
Mon Jun 17 23:26:41 2013 recv_socks_reply: TCP port read timeout expired: Operation now in progress (errno=115)
Mon Jun 17 23:26:41 2013 /sbin/route del -net 46.246.35.2 netmask 255.255.255.255
Mon Jun 17 23:26:41 2013 /sbin/route del -net 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.255
Mon Jun 17 23:26:41 2013 /sbin/route del -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0
Mon Jun 17 23:26:41 2013 /sbin/route del -net 128.0.0.0 netmask 128.0.0.0
Mon Jun 17 23:26:41 2013 Closing TUN/TAP interface
Mon Jun 17 23:26:41 2013 /sbin/ifconfig tun0 0.0.0.0
Mon Jun 17 23:26:43 2013 SIGTERM[soft,init_instance] received, process exiting
```

The routing table after connecting through socks.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         46.246.35.1     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
46.246.35.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
46.246.35.2     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
127.0.0.1       192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
128.0.0.0       46.246.35.1     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Using Linux and socks is really essential to me and i'm really clueless about this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to do something like https://superuser.com/a/644130 ?

Answer (score 1):

Is your proxy a SOCKS5 proxy? Or a SOCKS4 proxy?

I just had exactly the same problem, and nailed it down to the fact that (though undocumented), *OpenVPN only supports a SOCKS5 proxy*

FWIW, the SOCKS4 header is longer, and hence my proxy was waiting for additional data and timing out (`TCP port read timeout expired`) when OpenVPN connected.