# I would like to know how to use OpenVPN as proxy on localhost

Tags: windows, vpn

I would like to set up a socks proxy on local host that will dump the traffic only onto the OpenVPN interface.

So for example, if I set an application to use 127.0.0.1:1234, all traffic would be pushed through OpenVPN. And so, if OpenVPN was not running, this proxy would be broken.

Comment: It's possible, all the needed steps are described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1213865/285720).

Answer (score 0):

I think OpenVPN already does something of that kind - you do not need to set a proxy server; all your traffic is transferred through OpenVPN software, which sends the data to your OpenVPN server it's connected to.

It's like setting your server as the global proxy for the entire system and all programs - except that the connection and all data sent to / received from the server is encrypted.

How awesome is that?

Comment: The fact about OpenVPN (or VPN in general): it is NOT a proxy server; it is more than that. It's a Virtual Private Network with another computer, and it is (on the client-side) a new virtual network adapter which makes your system **use it** as a proxy.