# Routing only one Program through a VPN/Network card

Tags: networking, windows-8, vpn, routing

A user uses a VPN for tons of reasons, Privacy, Evading blockades, or using apps/programs that are blocked on a network, a great example would be a school network!

IRC's default port is blocked, solution? a VPN!

I've obtained a VPN with the name of [TunelBear](https://www.tunnelbear.com/), that provides 500mb free traffic, each month.

IRC doesn't use that much, but then again, I need my browser, Skype, and other applications to have internet too, 500mb wouldn't be quite enough, not enough to last a day!

When activating the VPN, ALL traffic is routed trough the VPN, with no option to disable certain programs.

That's where the question comes in, **How do I make sure, that only my IRC client uses the VPN (a windows network card), but NO OTHER program can?**

SideNote: I use a Windows 8.1 Laptop, with both Wired and Wireless internet options, which means there is a "Network Bridge" build into, to prevent cockups when using both connections at the same time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use VPN connection only for selected application](http://superuser.com/questions/294008/use-vpn-connection-only-for-selected-application), also see: [How can I make the Windows VPN route selective traffic (by destination network)?](http://superuser.com/questions/12022/how-can-i-make-the-windows-vpn-route-selective-traffic-by-destination-network)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks for the heads up, couldn't fond a dupe, i'll close this question

Comment: Why to close this question if another one does not have the answer anyway?