# Route specific traffic through VPN

Tags: windows-7, vpn, routing, network-traffic

I have a few questions, hopefully someone more knowledgeable than me can help. If I'm able to fix one of these issues it should help me out.

Running windows 7 32 bit business. I would prefer not to install any additional 3rd party programs.

I'm hoping that someone could give me some advice on how to either only route specific programs through a VPN (NetMotion mobility) or set specific programs to bypass the vpn. There is a policy rule in effect that significantly slows/blocks the 3rd party programs on the computer (chrome, iTunes, and several others). We are allowed to install these programs as long as they don't interfere with he computers security or network. I'm on good terms with one of the network admins and he let me install these programs. Unfortunately he can't help me out directly with the 3rd party issues. I would like to be able to set these programs to go directly through the wireless aircard and bypass the VPN  if possible.

On our work computers we have our primary computer dispatch service that only works on the vpn. I can reconfigure the server information, but I don't know what the server is, net motion handles this information exchange. Is there a way to look up the endpoint so I can leave the vpn disabled but still be able to connect to the cad server? Basically set my computer to go direct with the cad server. We were able to do this prior to both vpns though they changed the server info.

Prior to the installation of net motion and the policy rule, we would connect over the Cisco vpn. It wouldn't block or slow any other services. Before we used the Cisco VPN, everything was open and connected directly to the network through static ip's.

Usually what I end up having to do to get certain programs to work and update is have our network admin temporarily login and manually update everything over the network at our main building.

On my computer, I only have local admin access. I have no network level admin access.

Comment: My only issue with using a VM is that our computers are old and slow. I have a couple of other routes I can take, I'm just trying to think outside the box. I still try and find network flaws in my downtime at work, but I think they finally got me with NetMotion.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this can be done. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/294008/use-vpn-connection-only-for-selected-application) is a similar question.

You could use a VM and use specific programs on that, and have all of the traffic be through VPN as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/223754/is-it-possible-to-use-vpn-for-only-one-program).