# VPN and multiple devices

Tags: vpn

1. My laptop is connected to a VPN, via my WiFi router through an ISP. If I connect my mobile to the WiFi router, will my mobile net access go via the VPN? My guess is no, just wanted to confirm.
2. Is it possible to configure my laptop VPN (Ubuntu, OpenVPN) so that my laptop-internet access does not go via VPN and other (mostly Linux/bash) sessions are in VPN?

Comment: Where does the VPN start? Does it start on your laptop or on your router? As for #2, it depends on your configuration of the VPN (what calls it), which is a Linux question, not an InfoSec question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My laptop is connected to a VPN,

So your laptop runs a VPN client, and when connected to the Internet, it connects to a VPN server which is remote.

> via my WiFi router through an ISP.

ok WiFi is just how you connect to your 'router', the 'router' then connects to the Internet. How you connect to your 'router'(or the wireless access point of it) doesn't matter.

> If I connect my mobile to the WiFi router, will my mobile net access go
>   via the VPN? My guess is no, just wanted to confirm.

Your mobile is a computer.

If it is running a VPN client, then it will be able to connect to the VPN server and be on the VPN.

If it is not running the VPN client, then it will not.

> Is it possible to configure my laptop VPN (Ubuntu, OpenVPN) so that my
>   laptop-internet access does not go via VPN and other (mostly
>   Linux/bash) sessions are in VPN?

this superuser link [Use VPN connection only for selected application](https://superuser.com/questions/294008/use-vpn-connection-only-for-selected-application) asks that one.

It mentions a few answers, none of which i've tried. And comments don't really indicate whether any of them work or not.  But there may be other links about how to be selective about usage of VPN..

at worst you'd disconnect the VPN prior to using some apps, and reconnect for others.  Maybe a way for you to do what you want would involve a command toggling blocking/allowing the outgoing connections made by the VPN client.

Answer (score -1):

Ans1 - Yes it is possible but first you have to configure your VPN in mobile.

Comment: udi - please read [answer] to understand what we need from an answer post, and then edit in content to explain how

Comment: -1  so let's say he configured his VPN on his mobile. You should describe the process of how he can then choose what uses the VPN Otherwise your answer is not very useful.