# Run some programs through hide.me, but other programs without VPN

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, vpn

Basically when using a VPN, it seems like there should be an easy way to route certain network traffic on the local machine through the VPN, while not routing other traffic.  A more advanced or custom VPN might have a lot of settings built in to handle this sort of thing, but I've already looked into it for hide.me VPN, and it basically doesn't.

However hide.me VPN is still good for other reasons, so it would be nice if there were a network adaptor setting in Windows 10 or something else like that which would allow to, for instance, run Firefox traffic through hide.me, while tunneling game traffic through or around any VPNs.

Sysadmin / super user / network administration stuff isn't my niche, so what would be a real simple way to do this in Windows?  I looked over at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/294008/use-vpn-connection-only-for-selected-application), but didn't see an answer that looked like it could be used here.

While an answer covering VPNs in general would be nice, the question itself specifically pertains to hide.me VPN.