# Proxy to VPN connection fails

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, openvpn

What I want to achieve is to use a VPN connection via proxy so I can use it in individual programs that have a proxy setting, without having to run all my traffic through the VPN[*].

<sub>[*] the advantages of doing it like this - instead of using one of [these](https://superuser.com/questions/294008/use-vpn-connection-only-for-selected-applications) solutions - for me are 1) I'm not running openvpn on the host, so there is no way to mess it up in a way to accidentally route traffic through the VPN and 2) I don't have to mess with iptables or similar on my host, which I don't feel that confident about).</sub>

What I did: Create a VM (ubuntu on virtualbox) and install squid & run openvpn on it. So my connection (should) work like this:

```
App on host ---via-squid---> VM ---via-VPN---> the internet
```

There aren't any special configs I used; I've just installed squid and ran `openvpn --config ./some_config.ovpn`.

This used to work well, but for some reason it doesn't work anymore; instead, I'm getting a timeout (I'm not sure if something on the VPN changed, or if it's my system, or something else).

I tried to check each link in the chain, and they still work:

```
App on host ---via-squid---> VM ---without-VPN---> the internet
-> this works (so the problem isn't squid)

VM ---with-VPN---> the internet
-> this works (so the problem isn't the VPN)

App on guest ---via-squid---> VM ---with-VPN---> the internet
-> even this works (tested with "url --proxy localhost:3657 https://ipinfo.io")
    (so it seems that the problem also isn't the combination of squid and VPN)
```

Why does my connection time out when using the entire chain (even though each individual link seemingly works fine)?

Comment: Can you still reach your squid on the vm from your host, while VPN beeing turned on? Maybe there is a routing issue between the host an VM, if VPN is on.

Comment: @user3188140 I don't think so. I'm trying `nc [guest vm] 3128` and it doesn't give me anything, just stalls / times out. I can't connect to any other open ports either, and can't even ping the VM. So you are probably correct (but I'm not knowledgeable enough with network configs to fix this; do you have any hints?)