# Route traffic of certain websites to VPN connection

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

I have a vpn connection configured in windows 7 native client. I require that when I go to open.spotify.com in my browser (Chrome), all traffic to this site goes only through the VPN. Only for open.spotify.com. The question is how to do it?

Comment: Most VPN setups should route all your traffic through a VPN and you should have the opposite problem of makeing certain sites not use a VPN. What VPN setup are you currently using? What did you try to make this work? Do you need to pass all traffic from all software or just say for a specific browser? Did you consider using a proxy to do this?

Comment: @Seth, Im using PPTP VPN with native windows 7 client. Im tried to add route for spotify IP but it didnt work. Yes, from specific browser (Chrome). Yes, but proxy have high cost and VPN is free

Comment: @BlindSpots consider pointing out [How to ask a good](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) if you are concerned. Your comments aren't really that helpful right now.

Comment: @Peter VPNs and Proxys are neither free or paid by default. It depends on which you are using. You could check [Use VPN connection only for selected applications](https://superuser.com/questions/294008/use-vpn-connection-only-for-selected-applications) for some guidance. You should incorporate the technical details into your question to improve the quality and keep in mind that a "free" VPN has to make money somehow. So it might expose you to certain risks. If you do want to run Spotify in general keep in mind it might be using more URLs than what you can see in your adressbar.

Comment: @seth okay.  Good point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use VPN connection only for selected applications](https://superuser.com/questions/294008/use-vpn-connection-only-for-selected-applications)

Comment: Sorry, but no. I want to use VPN connection for certain websites, but not apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer.
Manual

1. Enter VPN connection properties->Networking->Double-click on IPv4 protocol->Advanced->Uncheck "Use default gateway on remote network"->Ok
2. Then connect to your VPN and copy IP that you received.
3. Open CMD and do `route print -4`, copy ID of adapter with vpn connection (it`s 25 by default)
4. Create a route using following command template:
   `route ADD *IP of website that needs VPN*/24 *IP of VPN from second item* IF *ID of VPN adapter*`